# Do the maths to call my name

Tags: riddle, calculation-puzzle

> My first one is my length.
>
> My second one is a bit closer to my third one than to my first one.
>
> My third one is my first and second together.
>
> My last one is four times my first one.
>
> Once you know all of us, you can call my name.

What is the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your name is

> DimP!!

My first one is my length.

> There are four numbers, so length is 4.

My second one is a bit closer to my third one than to my first one.

> 9 is closer to 13 than 4.

My third one is my first and second together.

> 4 plus 9 is 13.

My last one is four times my first one.

> 4 times 4 is 16.

Once you know all of us, you can call my name.

> 4-9-13-16 yields alphanumeric DimP!

Comment: Damn, that was fast! I'll make it more complicated next time, I think I should have left out maybe the hint about the length? Is that what gave it away so easily?

Comment: I'd upvote if I could, but I've reached my limit for today. Very nice!

Comment: @Brandon_J I'll do it for you :P

Comment: @DimP Not the answerer, but I think the 'call my name' combined with four clues leads to just one possibility.

Comment: The length gave the first part away, the last clue gave the fourth part away, and after that I had a pretty obvious blank in the middle which was conveniently filled. Great puzzle though, very creative!